# fixed point in the infinite, involving derivates, and composite of a $ C^1$ function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Hello this problem it´s looks easy, but I can´t do it. If you can give me some hint to do it )= 
It´s says this
Let $f:\left[ {a,b} \right] \to \left[ {a,b} \right]$ be $C^1$.
Let $p$ a fixed point of $f$ such that
$ | f´(p) | < 1 $ 
Prove that there exist $\delta >0$ such that for every $x \in \left( {p - \delta ,p + \delta } \right)\Rightarrow \,\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } f^n \left( x \right) = p$.

Where $f^n \left( x \right)$
denotes the composite of functions , $n$ times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: if $|f'(x)| < 1-\epsilon$ for $|x - p| < \delta$, what can you say about the relation of $|f^{n+1}(x) - p|$ to $|f^n(x) - p|$?

Comment: it´s only in "p" the inequality    $ | f´(p ) | < 1 $ where "p" is the fixed point

Comment: Yes I did it, i did not consider the hypothesis of being $ C^1 $ , with this the delta required for example can be taked in such a way , that $ f´(x ) < 1- epsilon $ as you said, thanks!